# Searching for a term in a text file using python

Tags: python

I'm really desperate for some help on this python code please. I need to search for a variable (string), return it and the data present on the same line as the variable data.

I've managed to create a variable and then search for the variable in a text file, however if the data contained in the variable is found in the text file the contents of the whole text file is printed out not the line in which the variable data exists.

This is my code so far, please help:

```
number = input("Please enter the number of the item that you want to       find:")
f = open("file.txt", "r")
lines = f.read()
if lines.find("number"):
    print (lines)
else:
    f.close
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you're looking for the string `"number"` in the list of `lines`... you probably want to do something like: `for line in lines: if number in line...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It goes like

```
lines_containg_number = [line for line in lines if number in line]
```

What this'll do is give you all the lines in the text file in the form of a list and then you can simply print out the contents of the list...

Answer (score 2):

See my changes below:

```
number = input("Please enter the number of the item that you want to find:")
f = open("file.txt", "r")
lines = f.read()
for line in lines:  # check each line instead
    if number in line:  # if the number you're looking for is present
        print(line)  # print it
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use 'with' loop, you don't have to close file. It will be handled by with. Otherwise you have to use f.close(). Solution:

```
number = input("Please enter the number of the item that you want to find:")
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if number in line:
            print line
```